# Syntax error in Python trying to calculate complicated interest

Tags: python

Here I have the following attemp to calculate complicated interest and mortgage interest for example. However it gives me syntax error on the TotalMonthsMortgage = TotalMonthsMortgage - 1.0 marking the first TotalMonthsMortgage /the one on the left/ and if I quote it it marks the next line AlreadyPaidAmount = AlreadyPaidAmount+TotalAmountMortgage/TotalMonthsMortgage marking the AlreadyPaidAmount on the left. What did I do wrong as I couldn't find mistake myself?

```
## Complicated interest is the bank interest for example charged for mortgage loans

TotalAmountMortgage = float(raw_input('Enter the total amount of the mortgage to be taken:')) ##this is Principal
TotalYearsMortgage = float(raw_input('Enter the number of total years of the mortgage to be taken:'))
TotalMonthsMortgage = float(TotalYearsMortgage*12.0)
TotalYearsFixedInterest = float(raw_input('Enter the number of years with fixed interest mortgage to be taken:'))
TotalMonthsFixedInterest = 12.0*TotalYearsFixedInterest
FixedInterest = float(raw_input('Enter fixed interest for the mortgage to be taken:'))
FloatingInterest =  float(raw_input('Enter floating interest for the mortgage to be taken:'))
PoolInterestPaid = 0.0
MonthlyPayment = 0.0
AlreadyPaidAmount = 0.0
FixedPayment = float(TotalAmountMortgage/TotalMonthsMortgage)
TotalPayment = float
while (TotalMonthsMortgage-TotalMonthsFixedInterest)>0:
   MonthlyPayment = FixedPayment+(TotalAmountMortgage-((FixedPayment*TotalMonthsFixedInterest+AlreadyPaidAmount))*FloatingInterest/1200
   TotalMonthsMortgage = TotalMonthsMortgage - 1.0
   AlreadyPaidAmount = AlreadyPaidAmount+TotalAmountMortgage/TotalMonthsMortgage
TotalPayment = (TotalAmountMortgage*FixedInterest*TotalMonthsFixedInterest)/TotalMonthsMortgage+(TotalAmountMortgage*TotalMonthsFixedInterest)/TotalMonthsMortgage+PoolInterestPaid
print TotalPayment                                              ##This is the total amount to be paid
print (TotalPayment - TotalAmountMortgage)                      ##This is the amount of intererst to be paid over time
print (TotalPayment - TotalAmountMortgage)/TotalMonthsMortgage  ##This is the amount of monthly payment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many parenthesis on the preceding line, you probably wanted one on the end too:

```
MonthlyPayment = FixedPayment + (
    TotalAmountMortgage - (
         (FixedPayment * TotalMonthsFixedInterest + AlreadyPaidAmount)
    ) * FloatingInterest / 1200)
         ----------------------^
```

I had to break the line across multiple lines to illustrate the problem, you may want to do the same to keep your code readable at least.

Because Python *allows* you to break the expression across multiple lines when using parenthesis, Python cannot detect when you *forgot* a closing parenthesis until the next line of code. The same applies to square brackets (`[]`), and curly braces (`{}`).

The rule of thumb therefor is to look at the *preceding* line too, when you encounter a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a paren on this line:

```
 MonthlyPayment = FixedPayment+(TotalAmountMortgage-((FixedPayment*TotalMonthsFixedInterest+AlreadyPaidAmount))*FloatingInterest/1200
```

Put a close paren at the end and you should be good to go.